# How to reload node js application without going to terminal and typing node app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, ejs

--------------This code is written in app.js--------------

```
const Anime_Images = require("anime-images-api");
const API = new Anime_Images();
getNSFWImg();
async function getNSFWImg() {
  let { image } = await API.nsfw.hentai();
app.get("/hent", function (req, res) {
    res.render("list", {
      Ejs: image,
    });
  });
}
```

-------------This is my list.ejs file---------------

```
<body>
    <img src="<%=Ejs%>">

</body>
```

This is the code I want to run.

When I write node app.js in terminal it shows me a Image on web at http://localhost:3000/hent.

But to see new Image I need to write node app.js in terminal again and again.

Is there any other way or a button on webpage I can set and when I tap the button it show me new image without me typing node app.js in terminal.

Note:I have already required all the modules in app.js

Comment: Use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can use a command line tool called "Nodemon" https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon. Once you have installed it you just run `$ Nodemon` this will run like running `$ node .` however when there is a chaange to a file in the current directory it will restart the app.